# Hanging/stuck reify:prettier: timing reifyNode:node_modules/@nrwl/workspace Completed in 12729ms

Tags: node.js, npm, yarnpkg

Details:

```
? Workspace name (e.g., org name)     swag                                                                          
? What to create in the new workspace angular-nest      [a workspace with a full stack application (Angular + Nest)]
? Application name                    swag                                                                          
? Default stylesheet format           SASS(.scss)  [ http://sass-lang.com   ]                                       
? Default linter                      ESLint [ Modern linting tool ]                                                
? Use Nx Cloud? (It's free and doesn't require registration.) No                                                    
                                                                                                                    
>  NX  Nx is creating your workspace.                                                                               
                                                                                                                    
  To make sure the command works reliably in all environments, and that the preset is applied correctly,            
  Nx will run "npm install" several times. Please wait.                                                             


[.....................] \ reify:prettier: timing reifyNode:node_modules/@nrwl/workspace Completed in 12729ms
```

Tools versions

- npm 7.6.1
- yarn 1.22.5
- node v15.12.0

[image]

Comment: TL;DR, Wait for few minutes to finish. Longer: The issue still exists as of Node 16.13.2 and NPM 8.4.1. It seems to be downloading under the hood, but not showing progress in CLI. In NPM 6 it showed progress-bar, which is not shown in NPM 7, 8.
To make sure its downloading, check Task Manager (Ctrl+Shift+Esc) -> Performance -> Network (on Windows); or System/Activity Monitor on Linux/MacOS.

Comment: See https://github.com/npm/cli/issues/4028. Downgrade to npm 6.X seems to be the best option as of now.

Comment: In my case the error only arise on a DigitalOcean instance. After downgrade to npm@6 it seems to work right for some days but then start failing again.
I must admin that after investigating the problem was due lack of free memory to run `npm install` and after increasing the droplet memory npm@8 works fine again.

Comment: dependencies HELLLLLLLLLL

Answer (score 49):

It's 2022, and this problem still exists. I was using Node.js 16.x/npm 8. To solve this problem, I simply downgraded to Node.js 14.x/npm 6.

Comment: Works for me on node v18 with npm 6

Comment: No. It's 2023 and the problem still exists.

Comment: No. It's 2024 and the problem still exists.

Comment: problems should keep existing while it is not paradise :)

Comment: dependencies HELLLLLLLLLL

Answer (score 38):

I got the same error and got it fixed by using node v12.0 which uses npm 6, I am pretty sure the error is linked to npm 7.

Comment: Downgraded npm with the following and it works great:
npm install -g npm@6

Comment: For clarification, after downgrading (which worked for me as well), you need to run `npm install`

Comment: [nvm](https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm) and [nvm-windows](https://github.com/coreybutler/nvm-windows) are really nice for switching between versions of node, btw

Comment: I have also done the same. It was not working on npm 8.5.0 but when I downgraded to npm 6.14.15, it worked. This is weird af :(

Answer (score 17):

Still a problem when using npm 8 when installing `opencv-build` package now, downgrade to npm 6 by `npm install -g npm@6` works.

Comment: Still a problem as of today on latest MacOS 12.2.1. Had to downgrade to npm6 using your command.

Comment: 1st January, 2023. Windows 10. Still a problem. Downgrading npm solves it

Answer (score 8):

In my case, pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> showed it was only downloading something:

```bash
...

npm ERR!      0K .......... ..........                                 100%  149K=0.1s
npm ERR!
npm ERR! 2021-12-24 16:11:52 (149 KB/s) - ‘/tmp/install_wasmedge.sh’ saved [21372/21372]
npm ERR!
npm ERR!
npm ERR!      0K .......... .......... .......... .......... ..........  0%  196K 3m23s
npm ERR!     50K .......... .......... .......... .......... ..........  0% 77.5K 5m58s
npm ERR!    100K .......... .......... .......... .......... ..........  0%  125M 3m58s
npm ERR!    150K .......... .......... .......... .......... ..........  0%  104K 4m34s
npm ERR!    200K .......... .......... .......... .......... ..........  0%  115K 4m48s
npm ERR!    250K .......... .......... .......... .......... ..........  0% 22.7K 8m50s
npm ERR!    300K .......... .......... .......... .......... ..........  0% 42.6K 9m46s
npm ERR!    350K .......... .......... .......... .......... ..........  1% 34.1K 10m57s
npm ERR!    400K .......... .......... .......... .......... ..........  1% 30.5K 12m7s
npm ERR!    450K .......... .......... .......... .......... ..........  1% 16.5K 14m52s

...

npm ERR!  16950K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 42% 26.6K 21m45s
npm ERR!  17000K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 42% 20.5K 21m41s
npm ERR!  17050K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 42% 16.4K 21m39s
npm ERR!  17100K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 43% 14.2K 21m37s
npm ERR!  17150K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 43% 14.0K 21m35s
npm ERR!  17200K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 43% 31.7K 21m30s
npm ERR!  17250K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 43% 27.6K 21m26s
npm ERR!  17300K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 43% 25.6K 21m22s
npm ERR!  17350K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 43% 15.1K 21m20s
npm ERR!  17400K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 43% 18.9K 21m17s
npm ERR!  17450K .......... .......... .
```

***=> See your network traffic log.***

Comment: How does this answer the question?

Comment: It answer the question. As stated, npm was not stuck but busy downloading a file.

Comment: WAITING solved the issue, it is not hanged. @jonrsharpe

Answer (score 7):

Same here.
node 18.12.1
npm 8.19.2

the only solution was to downgrade to npm v6 `npm install -g npm@6`

Answer (score 6):

In my case:
The problem was with npm 7, I've changed the version of npm by

```
sudo npm install -g npm@6
```

and re-run the command and boom... It worked.

Answer (score 2):

It's 2023 now. npm version 9.6.7 still has this bug. Downgrade to another version of npm like this:
`npm install -g npm@6`

Answer (score 1):

[image]

I am using latest versions, and its also stuck at lodash, than I wait for few minutes and fixed the issue automatically, using below command, just wait few time it will auto resolve

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Surprisingly, in my case, the issue was that I had a VPN on. Turned it off, and everything was back to being instantaneous.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same Kind of issue for **reifyNode:node_modules/@aws-amplify/cli/node_modules/readable-stream this**
I tried various combinations of versions

Then finally it works for the latest node version
and nmp version 6

node ----20.5.1 Current

npm  ----**npm install -g npm@6**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I found the information in this article - https://sebhastian.com/npm-install-hangs/ - helpful.

What worked for me was just starting fresh - deleting node_modules, deleting package-lock.json, npm install

Answer (score 0):

Using sudo npm install enables the installation of a package successfully in my case

Answer (score 0):

THis is probably a network issue where puppeteer tries to download big amounts of data for the browsers binaries. Other problems may be the source of this behavior as well, to get more info try:

```
npm i puppteer --ignore-scripts
```

This will make `npm` skip triggering installation scripts, thus, you need to do it manually:

```
cd node_modules/puppteer
node install
```

This will start the installation script and gives you more info on what's happening. Those info wouldn't be reported using `--verbose` flag in `npm install ...`