# npm install hangs at " reify:tailwindcss: timing build:queue Completed in 141ms"

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, tailwind-css, reify

It always hangs at the same place: `reify:tailwindcss: timing build:queue Completed in [number]ms`

I've even tried just walking away and leaving it overnight to no avail. What's really frustrating is this worked on another project for me about a week ago, but for the past two days I've hit this wall.

I've tried a couple of approaches I've seen here (each time removing the `node_modules` folder):

- `npm config set registry http://registry.npmjs.org/`
- `npm cache clear --force`
- Downgrading NPM to v6

Here is the `package.json` file:

```
    "private": true,
    "scripts": {
        "dev": "npm run development",
        "development": "mix",
        "watch": "mix watch",
        "watch-poll": "mix watch -- --watch-options-poll=1000",
        "hot": "mix watch --hot",
        "prod": "npm run production",
        "production": "mix --production"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@tailwindcss/forms": "^0.2.1",
        "alpinejs": "^2.7.3",
        "autoprefixer": "^10.1.0",
        "axios": "^0.21",
        "laravel-mix": "^6.0.6",
        "lodash": "^4.17.19",
        "postcss": "^8.2.1",
        "postcss-import": "^12.0.1",
        "tailwindcss": "^2.0.2"
    }
}
```

And here's the last few lines of output from `npm install --verbose`

```
npm timing reifyNode:node_modules/regenerate-unicode-properties Completed in 11736ms
npm http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/collect.js/-/collect.js-4.28.6.tgz 9769ms (cache miss)
npm timing reifyNode:node_modules/collect.js Completed in 12103ms
npm http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/webpack/-/webpack-5.47.0.tgz 10602ms (cache miss)
npm timing reifyNode:node_modules/webpack Completed in 12926ms
npm http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/caniuse-lite/-/caniuse-lite-1.0.30001247.tgz 10640ms (cache miss)
npm timing reifyNode:node_modules/caniuse-lite Completed in 13014ms
npm http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/lodash/-/lodash-4.17.21.tgz 10703ms (cache miss)
npm timing reifyNode:node_modules/lodash Completed in 13111ms
npm http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/tailwindcss/-/tailwindcss-2.2.7.tgz 10910ms (cache miss)
npm timing reifyNode:node_modules/tailwindcss Completed in 13289ms
npm timing reify:unpack Completed in 13331ms
npm timing reify:unretire Completed in 1ms
npm timing build:queue Completed in 113ms
⸨##################⸩ ⠦ reify:tailwindcss: timing build:queue Completed in 113ms
```

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66893199/hanging-stuck-reifyprettier-timing-reifynodenode-modules-nrwl-workspace-comp

Comment: @SarwarAhmed I just updated my question to show I had tried that, but forgot to mention it. Still no success, but thank you for the info!