# npm install is suddenly stuck

Tags: angular, npm, npm-install

I want to start a web application in Angular 17.
To do so, I've been running `npm install` before running `ng serve`.
This worked successfully so far, but suddendly stopped working.

Things I already tried to fix this issue include:

- Upgraded npm to latest (i.e. from 10.2.4 to 10.5.0)
- Uninstalled Node.js v21.6.2, deleted npm folders (`%AppData%\npm` and `%LocalAppData%/npm-cache`), rebooted my PC, reinstalled Node.js v21.6.2, executed `npm install -g @angular/cli` (which can be installed successfully) before attempting to execute `npm install`
- Uninstalled Node.js and reinstalled a lower version of it (20.11.1 LTS)
- Used `npm install --verbose` instead of `npm install`
- Used a VPN to exclude possible issues with the internet connection
- Deleted the `package-lock.json` file before executing `npm install`

Further possibly useful information:

- The registry URL is https://registry.npmjs.org/ as I expect
- I'm not using a proxy server

Has anybody ever encountered this issue?

When I execute `npm install`, the command remains hanging endlessly at this line:

```
reify:@esbuild/android-arm: timing reifyNode:node_modules/@esbuild/android-arm64
```

When I execute `npm install --verbose`, it looks like this:
[image]

The `package.json` file contains the following code. The `package-lock.json`is omitted for brevity.

```
{
  "name": "basics-assignment-3-start",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "watch": "ng build --watch --configuration development",
    "test": "ng test"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^17.0.0",
    "@angular/common": "^17.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^17.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "^17.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^17.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^17.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^17.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "^17.0.0",
    "rxjs": "~7.8.0",
    "tslib": "^2.3.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.14.2",
    "bootstrap": "3.3.7"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^17.0.0",
    "@angular/cli": "^17.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^17.0.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~5.1.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~5.1.0",
    "karma": "~6.4.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.2.0",
    "karma-coverage": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "~5.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "~2.1.0",
    "typescript": "~5.2.2"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I've seen this with different node_modules. It's usually a problem with the npm version.

Try to downgrade npm first: `npm install -g npm@6`

Comment: I downgraded to version 6 as you suggested. It looks as if it's working, eventhough I received several warnings when I executed `npm install` (see bottom). Why did you choose explicitly version 6?

`npm WARN read-shrinkwrap This version of npm is compatible with lockfileVersion@1, but package-lock.json was generated for lockfileVersion@3. I'll try to do my best with it!`  

Then also several `npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY` and `npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY`

Comment: It seems to be an issue from npm7 and above ( [link to the npm bug](https://github.com/npm/cli/issues/4028) the npm bug is still opened). You can use the latest version of node (20.11.1 at this time) but with npm6.

Comment: I think you should also read this [https://stackoverflow.com/a/70473330/7531430](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70473330/7531430). It says that it actually tries to download a file and it takes too long but eventually it ends. You could give it a try with latest npm over night if you are not in a hurry.